# Syntax error with a while loop in python

Tags: python

This is my script, its a script that works like a calculator, however when i run it, it gives me invalid syntax for the while loop? i am new to python help me please.

```
import functools
numbers=[]

def mean():
    end_mean = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers) / len(numbers)
    print(end_mean)

def sums():
    end_sum = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers)
    print(end_sum)

def whatDo():
    print('Input Extra Numbers '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
    try:
        number= int(input())
        numbers.append(number)
    except:
        print('What do you want to do?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == "mean":
            mean()
        elif answer == 'sum':
            sums()
        elif answer== 'median':
            median()

def median():
    numbers.sort()
    medianNumber=int(len(numbers))
    if medianNumber%2==0:
        end_median=numbers[int(len(numbers))/2]+numbers[int(len(numbers))/2+1]
    if medianNumber%2==1:
        numbers[int(len(numbers))+1/2

while True:
    print('Input Number '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
    try:
        number= int(input())
        numbers.append(number)
    except:
        print('What do you want to do?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == "mean":
            mean()
        elif answer == 'sum':
            sums()
        elif answer== 'median':
            median()
        print('Do you want anything else?')
        reply=input()
        if reply=='no':
            break
        elif reply=='yes':
             whatDo()
        else:
            break
```

i did remove the while loop but then it said that the print function was invalid. please keep in mind that i am new to python.

Comment: You're missing the closing `]` on the line before that.

Comment: Also, that line seems to be missing an assignment operation.

Comment: Why use `functools.reduce` to get the sum of a sequence? Just use the built-in `sum` function.

Comment: And the `median()` function doesn't print the median after it calculates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the while loop add the closing bracket to the line:

`numbers[int(len(numbers))+1/2]`

Usually it is a good idea to always check the lines above where the error occurred, if python is telling you that is found a `SyntaxError` but your syntax seems valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just before the `while` loop, there is missing `]` with the usage of `numbers` list

That line should be:

```
numbers[int(len(numbers))+1/2]
```

Comment: You're missing the `]` in your answer as well!